# Django: JSON response for AJAX pulling

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, jsonp

I have strange error, try to solve it in different ways.
In general -- i got response 200 and success status but data in empty, even when i browse data by url. 
One of code examples:

```
 #Django View    
 def api_recent_news(request):
     news = News.objects.all()[:2]
     r = [model_to_dict(v) for v in news]
     return JsonResponse(r, safe=False)
```

This ways i have nice JSON in browser. 
But when i try pull it with AJAX:

```
var url = 'http://this-is-my-url/api-recent-news/';
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: url,
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success: function(data) {
     console.log('Fetched ' + data.length + ' items!');
   },
   error: function(e){
     console.log(e);
   }
 });
```

So i got this response in console:

```
Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"}abort: ( statusText )always: ()complete: ()done: ()error: ()fail: ()getAllResponseHeaders: ()getResponseHeader: ( key )overrideMimeType: ( type )pipe: ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )progress: ()promise: ( obj )readyState: 4setRequestHeader: ( name, value )state: ()status: 200statusCode: ( map )statusText: "success"success: ()then: ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )__proto__: Object
```

Comment: You are doing a cross domain request with `jsonp`?

Comment: yes, as you can see: `dataType: "jsonp"`